# How to stop execution of CompletableFuture after timeout?

Tags: asynchronous, java-8, completable-future

I have a use case where CompletableFuture is running in a separate thread pool. We use Java8, so I have implemented a timeout mechanism using ScheduledExecutorService.

```
CompletableFuture<Void> cf = CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
// run some code asynchronously
}, executorService);
```

Below is the timeout mechanism I used, [reference](https://dzone.com/articles/asynchronous-timeouts):

```
final CompletableFuture<Void> responseFuture = within(cf, Duration.ofSeconds(3));
responseFuture
        .thenAccept(s -> log.info("Completed Asynchronous Processing"))
        .exceptionally(throwable -> {
            log.error("Unrecoverable error", throwable);
            return null;
        });


public CompletableFuture<Void> within(CompletableFuture<Void> future, Duration duration) {
    final CompletableFuture<Void> timeout = failAfter(duration);
    return future.applyToEither(timeout, Function.identity());
}


public CompletableFuture<Void> failAfter(Duration duration) {
    final CompletableFuture<Void> promise = new CompletableFuture<>();
    scheduler.schedule(() -> {
        final TimeoutException ex = new TimeoutException("Timeout after " + duration);
        return promise.completeExceptionally(ex);
    }, duration.toMillis(), MILLISECONDS);
    return promise;
}
```

I am manually testing the TimeOutException by adding Thread.sleep() - After the timeout takes place, it goes in the exceptionally block and logs the error but continues the execution. I want the `cf` which is running in the `executorService` to stop processing after timeout.

My understanding is that, since `cf` is running in a separate threadpool it is not aware of the TimeOutException and hence continues processing. How do I achieve this? Am I approaching this right?

Comment: `CompletableFuture` does not support stopping a task. And generally, stopping something requires active support from that code. You didn’t specific anything about your “some code” but the fact that it is compatible with the `Runnable` interface suggests that it does not support interruption.

Comment: @Holger Thanks for the clarification. I'm trying to write unit tests for the above code using Mockito but I'm getting nowhere. Could you perhaps give some pointers for that?